# Erro ao inicializar SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, services, sql-server-express

Eu tento inicializar o serviço do SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) e me ocorre essa mensagem de erro:

[image: erro sql]

O que pode ser?

Comment: Olá. Tal como o [gmsantos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16262/8113) sugeriu, se não encontrar o problema, ponha aqui o contéudo do erro que aparece no EventViewer para o podermos ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Não utilize o `services.msc` para iniciar os serviços do SQL Server. Ele não inicia corretamente os serviços do SQL Server.

Ao invés disso tente reiniciar o serviço utilizando o `SQL Server Configuration Manager`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais informações [aqui nesse link](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174212.aspx).

Caso o problema persista, utilize o `Event Viewer` para encontrar a causa raiz do serviço não ter sido iniciado. Já tive problemas de permissão de arquivos na pasta do banco `master` do SQL Server ao iniciar o serviço em uma conta sem privilégios de Administrador, que descobri a partir dos logs de erro.

Answer (score 1):

O que pode estar acontecendo é que o serviço do *SQL Server* está a rodar com o usuário `NT AUTHORITY\LocalService` mude para `Conta do Sistema Local`. Assim você conseguirá iniciar o serviço normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]